# d3.js Attributes, Transform, Translate when using polylines

Tags: d3.js, svg

My code is safely stored on my [bl.ocks site](http://bl.ocks.org/TheInsight/ec083b3e45b7fb19c304)

I've effectively converted a scatter plot into a hexagon plot by defining a polyline shape with 6 edges and referencing HEX in the code instead of circle. However, my scatter plot started neatly at (0,0) on the origin of my graph scales. My hex plot starts offset by -50,-20 and I can't find a way around it to revert it back to (0,0).

[Here](http://bl.ocks.org/TheInsight/0d76807fb88cdac17131) is the scatter plot code for info

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the `transform` on this line.

```
svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "path.hex")
    .attr("transform", "translate(50, 20)")
    .call(hex);
```

And potentially the 50,20 translating on this line (I think you may still need the scales)

```
hexs.attr("transform", function(d) {
 return "translate(" + xScale(d.Board) + 50 + "," + yScale(d.Alight) + 20 +  ")" + " scale(" + rScale(d.Totals) + ")"
})
```

Comment: updated my answer. I would also recommend diffing your non-hexagon code and your hexagon code to see what other differences there are. The path info needs to stay so you can draw the SVG, but any other code that was introduced should be relooked at.